# How do I add an image to a XML document?

Tags: xml, image, xslt, embed, dreamweaver

I am currently doing a markup for a catalog and need to include an image for each product but it needs to be an XML file. I am using an xslt stylesheet and so far am not having any luck successfully inputting an image.
Below is the markup of the catalog done in dreamweaver, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

XSLT -

```
  <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="size"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="salePrice"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="glazeType"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>

  <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="details &lt; 2022">
    <td id="highlight"><xsl:value-of select="details"/></td>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="details"/></td>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</tr>
```

XML -

```
    <code>bcpot003</code>
    <title>Copper Red Bottle 001</title>
    <size>60cm tall</size>
    <price>$550.00</price>
    <salePrice>$475.00</salePrice>
    <glazeType>Copper Red</glazeType>
    <description>Copper Red bottle form. Reduction fired to 1300 degrees</description>
```

Comment: Which image should be included where?

Comment: Do you know what XML you want to produce? (If not, you shouldn't be writing XSLT code yet). There are two things you might be trying to do: including an image by URI reference to an external file, or including it inline e.g. as base64. Or you could use a data URI which is a blend of the two approaches. From your question, we have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.